# python fastai TextLMDataBunch gives me "NaN in dataframe" error but there is none

Tags: python, dataframe, google-colaboratory, fast-ai

I am doing a test using fastai.TextLMDataBunch on Google CoLab and it gives me error:

```
# Language model data
data_lm = TextLMDataBunch.from_csv(path, 'train.csv', min_freq=1)
```

**error message:**

```
2 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/fastai/text/data.py in from_csv(cls, path, csv_name, valid_pct, test, tokenizer, vocab, classes, delimiter, header, text_cols, label_cols, label_delim, chunksize, max_vocab, min_freq, mark_fields, include_bos, include_eos, **kwargs)
    222                            label_cols=label_cols, label_delim=label_delim, chunksize=chunksize, max_vocab=max_vocab,
    223                            min_freq=min_freq, mark_fields=mark_fields,
--> 224                            include_bos=include_bos, include_eos=include_eos, **kwargs)
    225 
    226     @classmethod

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/fastai/text/data.py in from_df(cls, path, train_df, valid_df, test_df, tokenizer, vocab, classes, text_cols, label_cols, label_delim, chunksize, max_vocab, min_freq, mark_fields, include_bos, include_eos, **kwargs)
    198                                    include_bos=include_bos, include_eos=include_eos)
    199         if classes is None and is_listy(label_cols) and len(label_cols) > 1: classes = label_cols
--> 200         src = ItemLists(path, TextList.from_df(train_df, path, cols=text_cols, processor=processor),
    201                         TextList.from_df(valid_df, path, cols=text_cols, processor=processor))
    202         if cls==TextLMDataBunch: src = src.label_for_lm()

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/fastai/data_block.py in from_df(cls, df, path, cols, processor, **kwargs)
    135         "Create an `ItemList` in `path` from the inputs in the `cols` of `df`."
    136         inputs = df.iloc[:,df_names_to_idx(cols, df)]
--> 137         assert not inputs.isna().any().any(), f"You have NaN values in column(s) {cols} of your dataframe, please fix it."
    138         items = _maybe_squeeze(inputs.values) if len(df) > 1 else (inputs.values[0] if not isinstance(cols, Collection) or len(cols) == 1 else inputs.values)
    139         res = cls(items=items, path=path, inner_df=df, processor=processor, **kwargs)

AssertionError: You have NaN values in column(s) 1 of your dataframe, please fix it.
```

but my Dataframe contains none NaN values:

```
train = pd.concat([train_org['stance'], train_org['text']], axis=1)
train.isna().any().any()
```

it returns **False**

Anyone knows what's going on here? I really appreciate your help!

---

When I select partial dataframe (like 3,000 rows out of 50,000 rows) and do exactly the same procedure, it works.